# AJAX - Spring Controller - JSP

Tags: jsp, jquery, spring-mvc

I want generate AJAX (based on jQuery) request to Spring MVC controller and return Collection with objects to jsp. 
I have two troubles:
1. AJAX success block doesn't work (something with data type);
2. Don't know how to display this objects to the jsp.

```
<c:forEach items="${objects}" var="object">
    size : <c:out value="${object.size}" />
</c:forEach>
```

^
This code doesn't work.

My AJAX request:

```
    function AJAXItemRequest(name, surname) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url : "/pages/users",
            data : {name: nameValue, surname: surnameValue},
            success : function(data) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    }
```

Spring MVC Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelMap userHandler(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("name") String nameValue, @RequestParam("surname") String surnameValue ) throws Exception {
        Collection<Users> users = findConnectedUsers(name, surname);
        model.addAttribute("objects", users);
    return model;
}
```

Also, AJAX request works and controller successfully returns model Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working ,
To use Ajax with Spring you should use respose body and not ModelView

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchAlluserByQuery.do", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="content-type=application/json")
@ResponseBody public List<Object> searchAlluserByQuery(@RequestBody  String query) {

return serachService.getListByqueryContains(query);

}
```

Don't forget have jackson.jar on your class path
and in view layer Jstl not working for ajax!
you should use java script frame work such jquery
to get Json object