# How to return jsp page in spring mvc 3 ajax call

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a main page with header, footer, left panel and main content. I want to dynamically change main content on click of left panel. For this I am using ajax call, ajax will call controller and controller will return jsp which I will replace in main content.

But the problem I am facing is that I am getting JSP properly if I am using purely html coding but if I use spring form it is not working.

Do I need to declared taglib in all jsp or only in Dashboard jsp.

1. If I declare taglib in all child jsp then it not working and I do not declare then form:input do not render in to html
2. Can we return jsp in ajax call to replace with main content because [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673735/ajax-spring-controller-jsp) it says only @ResponseBody (JSON) can be used in ajax call.
3. I am using ajax call because I don't want to reload all my header, footer and left panel because they will always remain same.

Ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".ldMainContent").click(function(){
    var actionName = this.id;
    actionName = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sadmin/forward/"+actionName;
         $.ajax({
            url:actionName,
            type:"POST",
            data:"URL",
            success:function(result){
            $("#mainContent").html(result);              
          }
       });  
   });
    
</script>
```

I am using bootstrap in design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content can be loaded using jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

The code will be

```
$(".ldMainContent").click(function(){
   var actionName = this.id;
   actionName = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sadmin/forward/"+actionName;
   $("#mainContent").load(actionName);  
})
```

In your controller don't have `@ResponseBody` it is used to return object as JSON or XML. The controller should return a view for the JSP page which should only have the content that you want inside the `mainContent`.

> Do I need to declared taglib in all jsp or only in Dashboard jsp.

Yes you have to declare the taglibs which ever jsp file you are using the tags.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Actually my page was not getting rendered because there was an error of form binding and because of that form:input tag was not getting rendered. Your method also works but only get method is support in this.

Comment: Thanks for solving my others queries of taglib. I will mark your answer as accept, But is there any way to use post method in jquery load function.

Comment: As mentioned in the document http://api.jquery.com/load/ if you pass data then post method will be used.

Comment: how would I convert my url to object?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469443/string-url-to-json-object