# How can I dynamically change spring mvc variable in html without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have, server-side spring web service implementation, for example

```
model.addObject("someData", dataString);
```

this is called by a scheduler every minute for example.

then on the html (javascript) side

```
funtion timelyUpdate(){
    let dataStr = "[[${someData}]]";
    console.log(dataStr);
}
setInterval(function(){timelyUpdate()}, 6000);
```

on the server-side the variable is refreshed and is updated but on the html side nothing is changing. How can I make it so that every time the javascript code is updated by setInterval(), it updates the spring variable as well without refreshing the page?

Comment: As per my understanding of the question, you're looking for an Ajax call to your spring controller and wants to display the data from Ajax's response on your html page. Here's an example that might help you -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673735/ajax-spring-controller-jsp

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a rest service and then start consuming that rest service in your web page. E.g. how to do https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

But this will only work if you know the refresh rate in the server. Otherwise you might have to go with pub/sub architecture.

You can probably use a framework to do the heavy lifting but again depend on what you are trying to do even pooling might just work. https://cometd.org/ is a scalable framework for web messaging if you want to tryout!